# How do I find the parameters and headers I need to make a POST request?

Tags: python, linux, api, post, csv

Experts,

I'm working on Linux system with Python2.7. I have an URL that interacts with API, and in a browser, say Firefox, it returns a CSV file.

I'm having troubles accessing the url with a python script due to redirect (POST method).

Now, I have already found threads on the forum, demonstrating how to make a POST request. My problem is; how do I find the headers and parameters I'm supposed to send with the request?

Say, I would like to do something similar to this script:

```
import httplib, urllib
params = urllib.urlencode({'@number': 12524, '@type': 'issue', '@action': 'show'})
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("bugs.python.org")
conn.request("POST", "", params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
conn.close()
```

What *parms* and *headers* would I use in my request?

Following is the http response I recieve when I try to access the url with a simple wget command:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>HP Business Service Management</title>
    <script>
        function redirect() {
            document.getElementById("directAccessForm").submit();
        }
    </script>

   </head>

   <body onload="redirect();" >

       <form ID="directAccessForm" action="rfw/directAccess.csv" target="dialogFrame" metho
d="post" >

                    <input type="hidden" name="userName" id="userName" value="encrypt"/>


       </form>

       <iframe name="dialogFrame" id="dialogFrame" width="100%" height="100%" SCROLLING="no
" FRAMEBORDER="0" src="/topaz/static/act/blank.html" >
       </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Do I need any additional information to determine the parameters I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The website returns proper file because there's redirection with javascript.

You could download the file by accessing the url from form (action atribute of `<form>`):

```
<url of the website with form>/rfw/directAccess.csv
```

In case when you would like to access other forms with different values of action attribute you need to get that value e.g. with regular expressions.